# How to use MySQL-specific functions in H2 database?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, h2, spring-test

How can I persist an entity that contains a `@Formula` field in it to H2 database?

I encounter the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "UNIX_TIMESTAMP" not found;
...
```

Post class:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    // ...

    @Formula("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_date_time) / 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + likes_count")
    private long score;

    // ...
}
```

PostRepositoryTest class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class PostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Test
    void savePost() {
        entityManager.persist(new Post());

        List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();

        assertEquals(1, posts.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is specific to MySQL and is not supported by H2 automatically.

Comment: What happens if you start the H2 embedded database with `MODE=MYSQL`?

Comment: I added these in application-test.properties:
`spring.jpa.database=h2`
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testDB;MODE=MYSQL`
and added `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on the test class.
Now I get the following exception:
`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "POST" not found; SQL statement`

Answer (score 2):

According to https://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions, you could define such a function in `src/test/resources/import.sql`:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS UNIX_TIMESTAMP FOR "acme.H2Function.unixTimestamp";
```

and define the this class:

```
package acme;

public class H2Function {

  public static long unixTimestamp(java.sql.Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.getTime() / 1000L;
  }
}
```

Spring JPA will auto call import.sql when you start you unit test.

> NOTE: Must naming import.sql, not schema.sql, not data.sql